# Is it possible to set the text of TextView when the app isn't active/minimized?

Tags: android

I've created 2 different applications. One of them sends a text message(SMS), not much to it but it works. The second application is where my problem occurs, this application was created to implement broadcastReceiver and listen to incoming text messages and when a message is recieved it's supposed to set a TextView to the message received. It works in the sense that I can get the app to show a Toast message when I recieved a message from my other app. However, when I go in to the second app the TextView is not edited.

I've tried implementing both onResume(), onPause() and onStop(), onStart() to react when the app starts etc but nothing happens which makes sense, since the SMSReceiver class listens to broadcasts and it acts as soon as something comes up. It then creates an intent and since my app isn't up and running, nothing happens to the TextView.

```
// I have the permissions, I removed them so code is more clear


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS = 1;
public TextView msgDisplay;
IntentFilter intentFilter;

// vi skapar en
private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        msgDisplay.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("sms"));
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    msgDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgDisplay);
    checkForSmsPermission();

    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
}
}



public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = SMSReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String pdu_type = "pdus";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get the SMS message.
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String strMessage = "";
    String format = bundle.getString("format");

    // Retrieve the SMS message received.
    if(bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get(pdu_type);
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length;i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], format);
            strMessage = msgs[i].getMessageBody();

            Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
            Intent messageIntent = new Intent();
            messageIntent.setAction("SET_MESSAGE_ACTION");
            broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", strMessage);
            context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is happening because your main app is being killed when it goes to background. You should add a breakpoint in the onrecieve and see what happens. You probably should use a service to implement the onRecieve and pass it to your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SharedPrefrences`
So that, whenever you minimize or close the app your data will not lost.
As `SharedPreferences` method is used to store data.

It is similar to sessions in php.

Hope [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) link helps !

Answer (score 0):

As stated from previous post I would use `SharedPreferences` to allow for access once the phone is exited/closed. So in your class that is waiting for the message I would add the Shared Preferences code below to save the data for future access.

To **set** a Shared Preference use this code below:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("ID_NAME_EXAMPLE","STRING_TO_SAVE");
editor.apply();
```

To **access** the Shared Preference use this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String name = preferences.getString("ID_NAME_EXAMPLE", "DEFAULT_VALUE_IF_NONE");
```